# Ubuntu - tar.gz download error because website changed their address

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, tetgen

I am trying to compile dependencies of a C++ framework called `FW4SPL` with `cmake` in the terminal. By typing in the command `make -j4`, it will automatically download, build and install each dependency.

But there is an error during the compilation.

```
-- Retrying...
-- Using src='http://www.tetgen.org/1.5/src/tetgen1.5.0.tar.gz'
-- Retry after 5 seconds (attempt #2) ...
-- Using src='http://www.tetgen.org/1.5/src/tetgen1.5.0.tar.gz'
```

I think the reason is because the link at `http://www.tetgen.org/1.5/src/tetgen1.5.0.tar.gz` does not exist anymore and the company `tetgen` changed their website address to `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/tetgen_1.5.0.orig.tar.gz`.

I could manually open this `tar.gz` file but the problem is that I wouldn't know which directory this should be opened in because the `make -j4` command should do it automatically for me. The directory in which this `tar.gz` file should exist could be anywhere!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could file a bug against FW4SPL

Comment: Senyokbalgul, grep for the url "tetgen.org" in your source dir and correct the url in the CMake config file or where it is written.

Comment: @osgx it worked!

Comment: @Senyokbalgul, now it is **you** who must post full & detailed answer to this question to help others to fix this error. (As we have no detailed info on the fix - no filenames, no method of searching the problem, no quotes from original and fixes makefiles.)

Comment: @osgx ahaa okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the `tetgen` folder which is inside the source folder.

Change the line above into the one below and save and close the file.

```
set(CACHED_URL http://www.tetgen.org/1.5/src/tetgen1.5.0.tar.gz)
set(CACHED_URL https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/tetgen_1.5.0.orig.tar.gz)
```

Type in the command `make -j4`.